# Predicate logic, is this statement true or false

Tags: logic

I'm sorry if this is a noob question but I got this statement asked on a test:

$$\forall\ x \exists y \,F(x,y) \rightarrow \exists y \forall x \, G(x,y)$$
where

$$M = \lbrace \text{Natural numbers > 0} \rbrace \\
F(x,y): \, x <y \\
G(x,y): \, x > y\\$$

The statement is supposed to be false. I get that the left hand side is true but shouldn't the right also be true. Can $y = x$, since this is the only way that I could see this being false? Otherwise $y$ could be $1$ and all the other values for $x$ would be greater than $y$.

Comment: The only way you could see this being false, is a way after all

Comment: What was the accepted answer when the test was graded?

Comment: LHS = "For every natural number $x$, there exists a natural number $y$ greater than $x$." RHS = "There exists a natural number $y$ that is greater than any natural number $x$." Quantifier order is a significant issue.

Comment: @BrianTung Your interpretation, while perhaps intended by the problem composer, is not how the question is written.  Note that $~G(x,y):x >y,~$ so the RHS is asserting that there exists $~y~$ that is $~\color{red}{\text{less}}~$ than any natural number.

Comment: @user2661923: Oops, you are perfectly right! I somehow read $G(y, x)$, but that is clearly not what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

∃∀(,) says that we can pick a first number such that, whatever number we go on to pick second, the latter is larger than the former.

*Nothing bars us from picking the same number twice.*

So, as you put it, we can have $x = y$. Or least that's a sort-of-acceptable shorthand for an absolutely standard point about using quantified variables. In assigning values to variables in the standard semantical story about the quantifiers,  different variables are allowed to take the same value.

Comment: "the latter is larger than the former" (in the context) is "the latter, the number we pick second, $x$ , is larger than the former, the number we picked first, $y$" i.e. $x > y$ -- which is the right way round!

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I didn't read your question closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are right. LHS is true, and RHS is false.

```
∀∃(,) -- This is true, just take y=x+1
∃∀(,) -- This is false, let's take x=1, and there's no such y, that G(1,y).
```

So, you have True → False, which is false statement

Comment: See my comment, following the posted question.  There may be a typo in the posted question.